# SSO via HMAC and shared key. Can this be improved?

Tags: authentication, hmac, same-origin-policy, sso, replay-detection

Given an authenticated user on A.com, we want to redirect the user to B.com so that she'll be immedaitely authenticated. The scheme I'm considering is very basic:

A.com and B.com both share key **S**.

On A.com, redirect the user to https://B.com/auth?userid=**userid**&time=**current_time**&mac=**MAC** where MAC is HMAC-SHA256(userid + time, S).

B.com/auth requires that given MAC is valid and time is within 5 seconds of the clock.

Given the client will be on SSL, I figure a replay attack is unlikely but I've offered some minimal protection. I don't need anything like an OAuth login token; the client will always access B.com via this process.

Is there anything else I'm missing? Is there a formal name for SSO like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MAC is the right tool here, and HMAC/SHA-256 is fine. Using a 5-second tolerance might be a bit optimistic:

- You have to make sure that both servers have accurate clocks; use [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol). Also, make sure that you use a well-defined representation, i.e. something in UTC (otherwise, you'll run into trouble with Daylight Saving Time).
- The "5-second delay" must be enough to accommodate the round trip: server *A* sends the "redirect" response to the client, then the client connects to *B* and sends the request. If the client is in adverse conditions (e.g. a client using a laptop in a train), network can be unavailable for a few seconds at a time.

[Replay attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) from outsiders are prevented by SSL; the inclusion of the time stamp is to defeat replay attacks by the user himself. If server *B* requires a time stamp no older than *n* seconds, then this implies that if you block access to the user on *A*, then the user may still talk to *B* for *n* seconds. You can probably tolerate a longer *n*; personally, I'd use a 5 minutes delay. Another way to look at it is the following: if, once authentication was performed, *B* allows successive requests within a given time frame *T*, e.g. with a cookie-based session management and the session expires after *T* seconds, then it makes relatively little sense to use a *n* much shorter than *T*.

Note that an evil user may want to fake NTP packets in order to make server *B*'s clock go back to the past, in order to reuse an old authentication URL with a long-expired MAC. NTP packets are not authenticated. A normal NTP client will not accept to alter its clock by considerable amounts even if a NTP server claims that it is off by several weeks; however, a boot-time `ntpdate` call may be theoretically abused. I have not observed this attack in practice.

Suggestions for improvements:

- You may want to include an identifiers for *A* and *B* (e.g. server names) in the redirect URL, and as part of the MAC input. This keeps track of who is doing the authentication+authorization, and for what server the user is authorized. This is more flexible if you want to later expand the system with several distinct *A* and *B* servers.
- You can replace the MAC by a digital signature (RSA, DSA...): server *A* owns the private key and uses it to sign; server *B* uses *A*'s public key to verify signatures. This avoids sharing a secret between *A* and *B* (the more a secret is shared, the less secret it becomes).